# recognize which interface I using

Tags: linux, network-interface

On my laptop I've two interfaces (wlan0 and eth0), after conneted the wired, `ifconfig` show me "RUNNING" also in eth0. (both interfaces are in same network).

```
/sbin/ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,**RUNNING**,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500

/sbin/ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,**RUNNING**,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
```

How I recognize which interface I using?

Comment: Can you give the full output of `ifconfig` command?

Answer (score 4):

Try running `watch netstat -i` while traffic is flowing.  The active interface will have increasing counters.

The command `netstat -rn` may give you some more information.  I would expect traffic to flow on the interface with the lowest `irtt` value.

Comment: You can also use `dstat --net -N wlan0,eth0`. Dstat is an utility designed to monitor various metrics over time (run it without parameters for example) and is provided with all the major distros.

Answer (score 2):

`ip route` will show you where your system is sending packets. `man ip-route` will start you on a path to controlling where the packets go.